# HoloLens Deployment

Tags: hololens, deploying

I have build an application in unity and I am trying to test out my project on to holoLens. When I hit the run button I get an exit code 1 error.

I have already upgraded Visual Studio, debug deploy is  enabled.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some more information about the application you're trying to build and what settings you have in Visual Studio? From the screenshot it appears you are targeting x64 - to deploy to HoloLens you must change the Solution Platform to 'x86' in Visual Studio.